# Double everything in my db logs Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have double everything in my logs.  Not sure how to get rid of it.  Any suggestions?

```
  Bid Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bids".* FROM "bids" WHERE "bids"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 7]]
  Bid Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bids".* FROM "bids" WHERE "bids"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 7]]
  Size Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."order_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 7]]
  Size Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."order_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 7]]
  Bid Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bids".* FROM "bids" WHERE "bids"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 8]]
  Bid Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bids".* FROM "bids" WHERE "bids"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 8]]
  Size Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."order_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 8]]
  Size Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."order_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 8]]
  Bid Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bids".* FROM "bids" WHERE "bids"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 9]]
  Bid Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bids".* FROM "bids" WHERE "bids"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 9]]
  Size Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."order_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 9]]
  Size Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."order_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 9]]
  Bid Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bids".* FROM "bids" WHERE "bids"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 10]]
  Bid Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bids".* FROM "bids" WHERE "bids"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 10]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "printers".* FROM "printers" WHERE "printers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "printers".* FROM "printers" WHERE "printers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Size Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."order_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 10]]
  Size Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."order_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 10]]
```

Rails Version `Rails 4.2.5`
Ruby Version `2.3.0`

Comment: This could be related: [Rails 4 log messages appear 2x](https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/issues/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following to application.rb

```
        if Rails.env.development?
            # Don't log to STDOUT, by default rails s will handle it
            config.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
        else
            # Don't log to file, sending everything to unicorn file.
            config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
        end
```

Basically rails server and rails logger both send their messages to stdout which results in duplication in the logs.

Comment: I thought that this was fixed prior to rails `4.2.5`